# Back slash causing problems in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, escaping, backslash

I am generating some html in c# and assigning it to a literal in aspx using some data from database.
in below code `offtitle.Rows[off]["Offeringtitle"].ToString()` is bringing a value with a back slash '\'

```
sb.Append("<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"popupIncSummary('");
sb.Append(offtitle.Rows[off]["Offeringtitle"].ToString());
sb.Append("')\">" );
sb.Append(offtitle.Rows[off]["Offeringtitle"].ToString());
sb.Append("</a></li>");
```

This back slash is causing an error in javascript "Unterminated string constant" while page loading.

Please help me in this regards
Thanks

Comment: Why are you generating HTML in this fashion?  Why not use the view engine?

Comment: Then why are you manually serializing HTML with stringbuilder?  Use the bindings in webforms.

Comment: would you please elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of rendering your HTML using webforms instead of serializing using stringbuilder

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tempList = new List<object>();
        tempList.Add(new { Title = "test" });
        Repeater1.DataSource = tempList;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And in our view:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="#" onclick="popIncSummary(<%# Eval("title") %>)">
            <%# Eval("title") %>
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```